# Cast int to work on 64 bit architecture

Tags: c, xcode5

I get the following error when I'm running my XCODE project and it seems to be down to running my project as 64 bit. I can change this to 32 bit but any ideas on how I would cast the following code so it runs on 64 bit architecture.

```
int row = [indexPath row];
(implicit conversion loses integer precision: NSInteger (aka long) to int
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This is what NSInteger is for!

Comment: Cast it with a cast, of course: `int row = (int)[indexPath row];` ... unless `int` might be too small, in which case `long row = (long)[indexPath row];`. You could define row to be an `NSInteger`, but then you have no idea how big it is.

Comment: @JimBalter It is more important for the data to match than to know how big it actually is. Besides, even with `int` or `long`, you "have no idea how big it is" (it can vary between systems).

Comment: The only thing that is important is that all of the possible values can fit in `row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it says "implicit conversion". You can make the conversion explicit, eliminating the warning, with

```
int row = (int)[indexPath row];
```

or, if `int` might be too small,

```
long row = (long)[indexPath row]; // here the cast isn't even needed because widening is ok
```

Or you can make the type of `row` conform to the type of the value you're setting it from (if this is the only place you do so) with

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
```

Be careful if you change the type of `row` and then use it in a type-unsafe manner, such as an argument to printf ... make sure printf formats match the types of their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You should define `int row` as `NSInteger row`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies I tried NSInteger and this solves the error but doesn't actually run as expected when running the app in the simulator.

Comment: And it runs as expected with the `int row`?

Comment: @tau That's not likely to be because of the declaration of `row`. "doesn't actually run as expected" is mighty vague ... time to debug your code.

Comment: Thanks I will try to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: @tau Actually ... changing the type will matter if you are printing `row` via printf, e.g., with "%d" ... then you would need to cast `row` when passing it to printf.